# Packaging Wearable Apps with Ant

Tags: android, ant, build, apk, wear-os

According to [Packaging Wearable Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) it is possible to package Wearable apps with android gradle plugin.

Is it also anyhow possible with **Ant**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not try, but you can find some recommendations from Google [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually)